# Automatizar tarea en Excel y consulta sobre los campos que afecte la automatización

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, macros, microsoft-office, dbase

##### Soy nuevo en esto, no me maten

Estoy trabajando en una hoja de cálculo de Excel que contiene información sobre proyectos. Cada proyecto tiene un estado (por ejemplo, "En progreso", "Completado", "Pendiente") y una fecha de inicio.

Yo necesito algo que cambie automáticamente el estado de los proyectos a "Vencido" si han pasado más de 30 días desde su fecha de inicio y aún no se han marcado como "Completados".

¿Una macro para actualizar los datos es suficiente?
¿El dato se actualiza aunque nadie abra el archivo?
¿Cómo puedo simular el paso del tiempo para ver el resultado?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: *Una macro para actualizar los datos es suficiente?* Sí *¿El dato se actualiza aunque nadie abra el archivo?* No, se actualizaría solo cuando se ejecute la macro. Posiblemente puedas hacerlo con fórmulas sin necesidad de macros (mira la fórmula del SI) *¿Cómo puedo simular el paso del tiempo para ver el resultado* Utilizando fechas falsas